# Write a query to boost the results if it belong to a field of a particular type

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch with Node.js now the problem i am having is that i want to write a query such that i want to boost my result if it belong to a field of a particular type, for e.g if i have **index: merchants** and **types: restaurant, fashion** both types have a **field shop_name**, now i want my search result to get boosted to 2 times if shop_name is found in restaurant type instead of fashion.

My query i have wrote is given below

```
  index: 'merchants',
  type: ['fashion', 'restaurant'],
  body: {
     "query":{
        bool: {
          "disable_coord": true,
          should: [
          {
            "constant_score": {
              boost: 1.00, // HERE BOOST IS 1 as field is in type FASHION
              "query": {
                "wildcard" : { "fashion.shop_name" : last_wildcard_string }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "constant_score": {
              boost: 2.00, // HERE BOOST IS 2 as field is in type RESTAURANT
              "query": {
                "wildcard" : { "restaurant.shop_name" : last_wildcard_string }
              }
            }
          }
          ], "minimum_should_match": 1
       }
     }
  }
```

Now I don't know why but above code was working fine 2-3 months before i guess ,but now i don't know why above code is not returning anything.

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong because before it was working fine. Otherwise just tell me, **Is this not a right way to write fashion.shop_name to define shop_name of type fashion**.

Thanks Anyways.

Comment: What version of elasticsearch? Did you upgrade elasticsearch or the nodejs api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [{
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [{
                            "wildcard" : {
                                "shop_name" : {
                                    "value" : "last_wildcard_string",
                                    "boost" : 2.0
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term" : {
                                "_type" : "restaurant"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [{
                            "wildcard" : {
                                "shop_name" : {
                                    "value" : "last_wildcard_string",
                                    "boost" : 1.0
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term" : {
                                "_type" : "fashion"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}